# How to use std::find() with vector of custom class?

Tags: c++, vector, find

why does the following not work?:

```
MyClass c{};
std::vector<MyClass> myVector;
std::find(myVector.begin(), myVector.end(), c);
```

This will give an error.

> error: no match for 'operator==' (operand types are 'MyClass' and 'const MyClass')

However if I do the same thing with non-class datatypes instead of a "MyClass", everything works fine.
So how to do that correctly with classes?

Answer (score 12):

Documentation of `std::find` from http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/find/:

> `template <class InputIterator, class T>
>      InputIterator find (InputIterator first, InputIterator last, const T& val);`

Find value in range
Returns an iterator to the first element in the range [first,last) that compares equal to val. If no such element is found, the function returns last.

> The function uses `operator==` to compare the individual elements to val.

The compiler does not generate a default `operator==` for classes. You will have to define it in order to be able to use `std::find` with containers that contain instances of your class.

```
class A
{
   int a;
};

class B
{
   bool operator==(const& rhs) const { return this->b == rhs.b;}
   int b;
};

void foo()
{
   std::vector<A> aList;
   A a;
   std::find(aList.begin(), aList.end(), a); // NOT OK. A::operator== does not exist.

   std::vector<B> bList;
   B b;
   std::find(bList.begin(), bList.end(), b); // OK. B::operator== exists.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't compare two objects of your own class type unless you have overloaded the operator== to provide such a function. std::find() uses your overloaded operator== to compare objects in the range of iterators you offered acquiescently.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious: `operator==` is never implicitly defined / automatically generated for class types..

Comment: It would be nice if it were implicitly defined, for PODs at least. The lack of it means it's tempting to use a memset-memcmp to compare structs.

Comment: Oops. For some reason I thought it was a copy-assignment operator